# How to use LSI 9200-8e HBA with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, pci

I can't seem to get my card working. lspci command shows a card there but it's not the 9200-8e.

## lspci | grep -i sas

04:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)

I have a couple disks in my 8 bay SAS enclosure, the hard drive lights are on but I have nothing showing up in Ubuntu

any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed the drivers?

Comment: I can't find drivers...I've looked everywhere on LSI's website (now broadcom). Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to get some of the drives to show up. It seems to freeze when writing to any drive. I'm not sure I have the correct drivers. Anyone know of the correct one?